# Как восстановить приложение?

Tags: php, linux, yii2, apache2

Работаю на linux, делаю приложение на yii2-advanced, локальный сервер apache2.

Случайно сделал git checkout почти пустой ветки master и все наработки на ветке dev слетели.

Удалил приложение, заново сделал clone, pull, сменил ветку на dev.

Но приложение не работает, хотя ничего не менял.

HTTP ERROR 500

Как править?

Пробовал перезапускать сервер, не помогло. .htaccess-настройки те же.

Comment: Для начала нужно посмотреть в логи веб-сервера, возможно, там есть текст ошибки

Comment: не в сервере было дело

Comment: Конечно что не в сервере, но в логе можно найти человеческое описание ошибки

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

1. Удалил папку проекта.
2. С помощью `composer` установил чистый проект yii2-advanced
3. Сделал `git fetch --all` внутри папки чистого проекта
4. Сделал `git reset --hard origin/master`
5. Сделал `git pull origin dev`
6. Заново настроил подключение к базе данных (не знаю почему сбилось)
7. Создал заново ветку `dev`
8. Заново настроил права `chmod`

После этого проект снова прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее частой причиной ошибки 500 (Internal Server Error, внутренняя ошибка сервера) является неверный синтаксис файла .htaccess или наличие в нем неподдерживаемых директив. Чаще всего достаточно закомментировать директиву Options (для этого нужно поставить в начале строки решетку — #), и проблема исчезнет.

Ошибка 500 также может возникать вследствие неправильного обращения с CGI-скриптами:

CGI-скрипты должны иметь окончания строк в формате UNIX (\n), а не в формате Windows (\r\n). Для этого их надо загружать на сервер по FTP в режиме ASCII.

CGI-скрипты и папки, в которых они находятся, должны быть доступны для записи только владельцу, то есть иметь права 0755 (drwxr-xr-x).

В результате работы CGI-скрипта сформированы неправильные HTTP-заголовки ответа. В этом случае для решения проблемы полезно обратиться к error_log (его можно найти в контрольной панели в разделе «Хостинг / Статистика / Лог-файлы / Ошибки»).

Comment: работаю локально, без хостинга

Comment: работаеш на xampp??

Comment: нет, на lamp. хотя по сути тот же xampp.

Comment: тогда иши проблему на file php.ini смотри что ты изменил

Comment: у меня был тот же ошибка 500 server  смотрел на php.ini  и наконец через 3 часа нашол тот строку которую сам изменил_)))

Comment: я же написал, что ничего не менял, кроме того, что сделал git checkout и переустановил проект.

Comment: и не забудь перезагрузиить  lamp после изменение